# Can I pass data from Winforms to WPF Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, winforms-interop

I have a winforms app but I would like to introduce a WPF user control into the app as a taster for further WPF implementation.

This control needs to receive from its Host a single piece of information, a string. How can I pass this down from the Winforms app to the hosted control?

Or, indeed, can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. Extend your WPF User Control with methods to set whatever data you want and call them from within WinForms application. See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_UserControls.aspx) for example.

Comment: Looks helpful. Will try this.

Answer (score 5):

Assign properties of wpf control after creating an instance and before giving the reference to host's childes

```
WpfUserControl ctrl = new WpfUserControl();
ctrl.Data = passedData;
ElementHost1.Child = ctrl;
```

Comment: This also looks pretty good, but not right for my usage scenario at present. However it could one day be a life saver.

Comment: Why doesn't this match your scenario?

Comment: My control was not dynamically added, it was already on the form. The other answer is now in use and works beautifully. In fact, if I were to dynamically add the control I would probably give the control settable properties as the chosen answer recommends.